# Display Random Webpage From Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I couldn't find an existing answer which quite solved my problem.

I have a domain, `http://bonfiredog.co.uk`, which has an `index.html`. I also have some other webpages in HTML form; let's call them:

```
splash1.html 
splash2.html 
splash3.html
```

I would like people, when they visit my domain, to have one of these webpages displayed at random.

I am assuming that I can do this by running a jQuery script in the index.html, but I can't seem to reverse-engineer a solution. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var redirectUrls = [
'http://bonfiredog.co.uk/splash1.html',
'http://bonfiredog.co.uk/splash2.html',
'http://bonfiredog.co.uk/splash3.html',
]

var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() *3);

location.href = redirectUrls[randomNumber];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of your locations, then generate a random index from your array, get the item at the random index and redirect to that location.

The following function should work for you:

```js
$(function() {
  var targets = ['splash1.html', 'splash2.html', 'splash3.html'];
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * targets.length);
  window.location = targets[index];
});
```